# Combining Update Statement with Join

Tags: sql, join, sql-update

I'm having a problem.  I need to update a table using plsql, but the condition in the where clause will depend upon conditions in a different table. For example

```
UPDATE table1
set column1 = ...
where table2.column = ...
```

This isn't what I have.  However, I do need to know how to properly do this.

Comment: The accepted answer can not possibly work "using plsql", because PL/SQL is Oracle's stored procedure language which suggests you *are* using Oracle - but that doesn't support JOIN in an `UPDATE` statement. Please tag your question with the DBMS you are using. (And besides: a simple `UPDATE` statement is not PL/SQL, it's plain SQL in Oracle)

Comment: Would you like me to repost my question again and change the tag, or could I just indicate the DBMS here?

Comment: I'm using Oracle SQL Developer.

Comment: SQL Developer is a SQL *client*, not a DBMS. And it can connect to various DBMS (Oracle, MySQL, SQL Server, Postgres...)

Comment: Okay, sorry.  I'm still new to this.  In that case, I believe that my DBMS is Oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you use a `JOIN` in an `UPDATE` query:

```
UPDATE table1 AS t1
JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.somecol = t2.someothercol
SET t1.column1 = ...
WHERE t2.column = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write an update command as follows:

```
UPDATE employees e SET taxable = 'Y'
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SALARIES s 
                WHERE s.employee_id = e.employee_id 
                  AND s.salary > LOWER_LIMIT)
```